# Bamboo variable display name instead of value in case variable doesn't exist

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo

I have a use case where the variable `${bamboo.ManualBuildTriggerReason.userName}` didn't exist (for example in case bamboo plan was triggered by the git commit) If this happens I receive a variable name in format `${bamboo.ManualBuildTriggerReason.userName}` instead of an empty or null value. Can I do something to prevent this behavior? I want to have empty value or some sort of null value

Answer (score 1):

The only one way to I found its workaround in sh script

```
originUsername='${bamboo.ManualBuildTriggerReason.userName}'
processedUsername=${originUsername//\$\{bamboo\.ManualBuildTriggerReason\.userName\}/Auto Build}
```

In the first string bamboo will replace placeholder for the real value (but in case of bamboo will not have any value to set you will receive string ${bamboo.ManualBuildTriggerReason.userName})

In the second line, I just replace bamboo placeholder with Auto Build.

In the end we have real value if set or 'Auto Build' if bamboo didn't have any value

Comment: Use the simpler `${bamboo.ManualBuildTriggerReason.userName:-Auto Build}`

Comment: @Alex I don't know why... but it doesn't work in my case

Comment: Replace the dots with underscores.

Comment: @Alex Unfortunately...

Comment: Well, mention the error next time if you need help!